# How to include routing in ApplicationHelper Spec when running trough Spork?

Tags: rspec, helper, rails-routing, spork

I have an rspec spec:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe "#link_to_cart" do
    it 'should be a link to the cart' do
      helper.link_to_cart.should match /.*href="\/cart".*/
    end
  end
end
```

And the ApplicationHelper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_cart
    link_to "Cart", cart_path
  end
end
```

This works when visiting the site, but the specs fail with a RuntimeError about Routing not being available:

```
RuntimeError:
   In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly. For instance, `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

So, I included the `Rails.application.routes.url` in my spec, the `spec_helper`-file and even the `ApplicationHelper` itself, to no avail.

Edit: I am running the tests via spork, <strike>maybe that has to do with it</strike> and is causing the issue.

How must I include these route helpers when running with Spork?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `include` at module level of `ApplicationHelper`, because ApplicationHelper doesn't include the url helper by default. Code like this

```
module AppplicationHelper
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  # ...
  def link_to_cart
    link_to "Cart", cart_path
  end

 end
```

Then the code will work and your test will pass.

Comment: I already tried that, and it does not make the test pass: the failure message stays the same.

Comment: @berkes, I've already verified that in my console before posting the answer. It works. In your question, I only saw you mentioned including it in test, but not ApplicationHelper module. That is incorrect.

Comment: It's also NOT `ApplicationController`, but `ApplicationHelper`

Comment: My wrong; a mistake in the question, but it changes little about my problem. I suspect spork being the problem here and will try moving that out and re-testing.

Comment: @berkes, I don't use Spork but plain Rspec. I just wrote test for helper for a static page in same code. And it passed. No sure why you got error.

Comment: any idea on how to include the application helper in an initializer:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035947/rails-4-use-application-helpers-inside-initializers

Answer (score 6):

If you are using [spork](https://github.com/sporkrb) with [rspec](http://rspec.info/), you should add the url_helper method to your rspec config -

Anywhere inside '/spec/spec_helper' file:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ...
end
```

this loads a built-in ApplicationHelper called "Routes" and calls the '#url_helpers' method into RSpec. There is no need to add it to the ApplicationHelper in '/app/helpers/application_helper.rb' for two reasons:

1. You are just copying 'routes' functionality into a place that doesn't need it, essentially the controller, which already inherits it from ActionController::Base (I think. maybe ::Metal. not important now). so you are not being DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself
2. This error is specific to RSpec configuration, fix it where it's broke (My own little aphorism)

Next, I'd recommend fixing your test a little. Try this:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe "#link_to_cart" do
    it 'should be a link to the cart' do
     visit cart_path 
     expect(page).to match(/.*href="\/cart".*/)
    end
  end
end
```

I hope that this is helpful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

I was using `guard` with `spring` and I found out that, in my case, the issue was caused by spring. After running `spring stop` it was fixed. But it keeps coming back sometimes when I change something in an `ApplicationController`.