# rails 4 use application helpers inside initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, initialization

Is it possible to include / use Application Helper methods inside of an `config/initializers/browser_blocker.rb`?

I am using the [browser gem](https://github.com/fnando/browser) to detect and block older non modern browsers.

```
Rails.configuration.middleware.use Browser::Middleware do
    include ApplicationHelper
    redirect_to :controller => 'error', :action => 'browser-upgrade-required' if browser_is_not_supported
end
```

Helper method I am currently working with:

```
  # test browser version
  def browser_is_not_supported
    return true unless browser.modern?
    return true if browser.chrome? && browser.version.to_i < ENV['BROWSER_BASE_VERSION_GOOGLE'].to_i
    return true if browser.firefox? && browser.version.to_i < ENV['BROWSER_BASE_VERSION_FIREFOX'].to_i
    return true if browser.safari? && browser.version.to_i < ENV['BROWSER_BASE_VERSION_SAFARI'].to_i
    return true if browser.opera? && browser.version.to_i < ENV['BROWSER_BASE_VERSION_OPERA'].to_i
    return true if browser.ie? && browser.version.to_i < ENV['BROWSER_BASE_VERSION_MSFT'].to_i
  end
```

Comment: why do you need `ApplicationHelper` functionality there? It would be best to just use the specific modules instead, hard to give an example since your example is not using any helper methods

Comment: because I was hoping to use the browser_is_not_supported in other parts of the application? Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
# lib/browser_util.rb
module BrowserUtil
  def self.supported?(browser)
    # your code ...
  end
end
```

and wrap that from ApplicationHelper for use in views

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def is_browser_supported?
    BrowserUtil.supported?(browser)
  end
end
```

in middleware

```
Rails.configuration.middleware.use Browser::Middleware do
  unless BrowserUtil.supported?(browser)
    redirect_to :controller => 'error', :action => 'browser-upgrade-required' 
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:** it does not need to be in a separate module (BrowserUtil)

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def self.foo
    "FOO"
  end

  def foo
    ApplicationHelper.foo
  end
end
```

in middleware use

```
ApplicationHelper.foo
```

in views it would use the included method

```
foo
```

Comment: I like this idea a bit better based on your recommendations, but now I am getting "undefined local variable or method `browser' for ApplicationHelper:Module"

Comment: ahh, I forgot to send (browser), I think I have this now, testing atm

Comment: FIXED! THANKS! I liked your points about overriding methods. That could have been dangers, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can but that's bad idea, i agree with that that logic supposed to somewhere in `app` but sometime you have to deal with it. I am saying this because you can block the request before `old_browser` request gets it and load `rails stack`.

Anyway, this is how can you can do it

```
Rails.configuration.middleware.use Browser::Middleware do
  self.class.send(:include,ApplicationHelper)
   redirect_to :controller => 'error', :action => 'browser-upgrade-required' unless    browser_is_supported?
end
```

Comment: Like @Paritosh said - "but that's bad idea": just to be clear you are mixing ALL of the methods from your ApplicationHelper into this class: https://github.com/fnando/browser/blob/master/lib/browser/middleware.rb , so if you were to add any methods with the same names to ApplicationHelper your new method will overwrite the browser version - these types of defects are very hard to track down when they occur

Comment: so, would you rather go for duplicating the method in 2 places? I am not opposed to switching it to your version @house9 if you feel that would be better in the long term.

Comment: its not really duplicated, but 'callable' via class method or instance method - I personally would go that route instead of using `include` in this specific case